# Is it possible to extend Visual Studio Solution Explorer to open files that are not *.sln?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-sdk, solution-explorer

I know it is possible to create a new tool window when extending Visual Studio 2015, but is it possible to make the solution explorer open something other 
than an MSBuild solution file?

---

My goal is to explore the idea of creating a Visual Studio 2015 extension for an alternative language that is not .NET based (I just like the VS IDE). Part of that is to open up an "Q solution" (*.qms). A qms file, similar to a sln file, is just an xml file of individual qmx projects, which again are just xml files, etc. etc.

I tried looking at how the Boo language was extended for Visual Studio, but that is a language that compiles into a .NET assembly just as C# and VB do, and it doesn't seem that it really takes over the solution explorer.

Comment: I'd guess the answer is "No" but then again a solution is just a wrapper for the project files, so you'd rather have to look into making your qmx project files known to VisualStudio and not care much about creating a custom solution file format.

Comment: As long as you comply to the XML DTD  that visual studio can understand

Comment: I'm not sure about replacing the sln file, but you can have custom project hierarchies, just look at [Java Language Support](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93). The extension has a custom hierarchy for *.javaproj, including custom properties windows, etc. [Source Code](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/JavaForVS/blob/master/Tvl.VisualStudio.Shell.Implementation/StandardTaskSchedulers.cs)

Comment: So far the project system and so on are sln and MSBuild based. Will have to wait till Microsoft makes changes in the future. For example, Visual Studio Code does not depend on MSBuild.